# Should I commit my .terraform-version file?

Tags: terraform

Should my `.terraform-version` file be added to source control/Git?

This seems like an easy and explicit way to ensure multiple developers use the same Terraform binary if provisioning infrastructure from their local machines, but I can't see any guidance suggesting as much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `.terraform-version` file is not something considered by Terraform itself, but some third-party "version manager" tools such as [`tfenv`](https://github.com/tfutils/tfenv) can use it to automatically select a suitable Terraform version.

If your intention is to help ensure that everyone on your team is using the same version of Terraform then I think it *would* make sense to place that file under version control, and then you can handle changes to the selected Terraform version by the same change review process you use for any other changes to your Terraform configuration.

However, since `.terraform-version` is a concept belonging to third-party version managers rather than Terraform itself you will need to also ensure that everyone on your team agrees to use version manager software that supports that convention. Anyone who just installs and runs a particular version of Terraform manually will not automatically benefit from that file being present.

Comment: Thank you for this! I had completely forgotten that I was using `tfenv` ‍♂️.

Answer (score -1):

You should avoid committing the .terraform-version file to your repository for several reasons:

**Compatibility**: The .terraform-version file specifies the desired Terraform version for your project. This version requirement can vary between projects and even change over time as Terraform releases new versions. Committing this file to your repository means that everyone who clones or pulls the repository will be forced to use the exact same Terraform version, which may not always be appropriate.

**Locking Versions**: While specifying a specific Terraform version can be useful for consistency, it can also be restrictive. In some cases, you may want to allow developers to use a newer version of Terraform if it doesn't break compatibility with your configuration. If you commit a .terraform-version file, it becomes harder for team members to use a different version without modifying the file (which should be avoided in version-controlled files).

**Team Flexibility**: Different team members or environments might have different Terraform versions installed. By not committing the .terraform-version file, you allow developers to use the Terraform version they have installed locally or that's available in their specific environment.

**Avoiding Merge Conflicts**: If every developer commits changes to the .terraform-version file to specify their preferred version, it can lead to frequent merge conflicts in the repository. This can become cumbersome to manage, especially in larger teams.

You should add something like the following to .gitignore

```
#  Local cache
**/.terraform/*

# State
*.tfstate
*.tfstate.*
*.terraform.lock.hcl
```